# Error when checking pointer is 64 byte aligned or not

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting compilation error when I am checking if an address is 64 byte aligned or not.

error: invalid operands to binary expression ('void *' and 'int')

```
  #define BYTE_ALIGNMENT 64
  void *is_mem_aligned(void* ptr){

    if(ptr%BYTE_ALIGNMENT == 0){
          printf("already aligned %p\n",ptr);
          return ptr;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't perform arithmetic (except addition and subtraction, but they have special meaning) on pointers because they're not numbers. If the C implementation you're working on defines `uintptr_t`, you can cast them to `uintptr_t` and perform arithmetic on numbers that "should" in some sense match the addressing model. So:

```
if((uintptr_t)ptr % BYTE_ALIGNMENT == 0){
```

Aside from this, alignment is not *testable*. A declared object of a given type is suitably aligned for its type, and memory obtained by `malloc` is suitable for any type not overaligned via `_Alignas`. Then, if `p` is aligned mod `N`, `(char*)p+k*N` is aligned for any integer `k` for which the sum is defined. Your program logic has to *preserve* alignment where needed if you do anything funny; you can't *test* it.